# PyQT5 QComboBox dropdown list persists after event is signalled

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I'm new to using pyQT for GUIs, but have a couple of years of experience using Java GUIs.

I have a QComboBox for choosing an option, and then a submit button to initiate calculations for a plot, given the choice. Everything works great, except when matplotlib shows the plot, the dropdown list from the QComboBox persists separate from the choice window or plot window. It even occupies the top layer of my screen, so I can't keep the plot open while working in other windows. Being completely new to pyQT I'm not sure where to begin with fixing the issue.

I'm using the PyQt5 from Anaconda which is version 5.9.2
And my os is macOS Mojave, 10.14.6

Here is a version of my code that, when run, produces the error:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

app = QApplication([])

window = QWidget()

layout = QGridLayout()
layout.setSpacing(10)

label = QLabel("Choose an option")
layout.addWidget(label, 0, 0, 1, 3)

button = QPushButton("Submit")
layout.addWidget(button, 1, 1)

ifo_choices = { 'x','x^2','e^x','sin(x)' }
choose = QComboBox()
choose.addItems(ifo_choices)
layout.addWidget(choose, 2, 1)

def submit_pref():
    pref = choose.currentText()

    freq = np.linspace(0,10,100)

    if(pref == 'x'):
        y = freq
    elif(pref == 'x^2'):
        y = freq**2
    elif(pref == 'e^x'):
        y = np.e**freq
    elif(pref == 'sin(x)'):
        y = np.sin(freq)

    plt.plot(freq, y)
    plt.show()

button.clicked.connect(submit_pref)

window.setLayout(layout)

window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Here is what the issue looks like on my computer:

[image: Issue]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: provide a [mre], what is your pyqt5 version?

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm using the 5.9.2 that is included with anaconda

Comment: okay, you need to provide the MRE, also indicates which your OS (version), maybe a bug.

Comment: The original code provided should have been enough to reproduce the error, but for clarity I created a separate program dedicated to reproducing the error.

Comment: I've tried it on my machine, and it worked perfectly. I can choose any of the functions (the dropdown list appears where it should), click submit, the graph appears. Closing that, and choosing a different function works as well. The bug is not in your code.
(up-to-date Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, Python 3.6.8, python3-pyqt5 5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2)

Comment: Ok, I've checked it on my Windows 10 partition, and it works perfectly as well. I've installed this long ago, there must be newer versions as well. (Windows 10 Home 1903 (18362.418), Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51), PyQt5 5.11.3 from pip)